# Is there another way to get data from Teradata other than ODBC?

Tags: vb.net, nuget, ado.net, odbc, teradata

As per title I would ask if are there native (or not) methods to connect to Teradata using e.g. SqlConnection or OledbConnection Classes (or other if any).

In first place, because I guess being ADO's Recordset a legacy, other methods could perform better, in second because ADO.net introduced Datasets which are not currently supported.
I know there are extensions (which I already downloaded) as NuGet packages Teradata.Client.Provider and Teradata.EntityFrameworkCore but being a newbie I don't know how to use them, and there is no instructions both on the web or in the documentation (I just can't even figure out how to connect or send a query).

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Well, on the nuget website there's a link to the *Developer's Guide* https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/17.20/help/webframe.html